# multiple functions on jquery on method

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to call multiple functions on jquery on method. I need to combine both  functions into one.

```
$('.car li').on("click",carupdate)
$('.car li').on("click",cardelete)

function carupdate()
{ 
// some stuff
}
```

and `cardelete()` is also kind of similar.

Is it possible to combine functions?

Comment: Why not just combine the functions into one, or just call the second function at the end of the first one?

Comment: why would you call both update and delete?

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
$('.car li').on("click",function(){carupdate();cardelete()})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the methods stack, so `carupdate` will be called and `cardelete` will both be called.